# How to send ArrayList data to server using volly in android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-volley

I have some data in arraylist like myList=[0,1,2]  and I have to send to sever now .I am sending request using StringRequest so I am getting some error in Logcat.I think I should send request using JsonObject Request,isn't it?

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("clientid", clientidd);
    params.put("doc_type",myList);
    params.put("taxpreparerid", taxpreid);

    System.out.println("my lIst"+myList);
    System.out.println(params);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting? Please provide a reasonable code.

Comment: <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
    <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
    <p>Severity: Warning</p>
    <p>Message:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()</p>
    <p>Filename: api/Document.php</p>
    <p>Line Number: 403</p>
     <p>Backtrace:</p>

Comment: When i send any data from POST MAn ,data is posted successfully.

Comment: It seems some problem with your php code. I can't see any code in android for network call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three errors in your code .

```
@Override
                public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("clientid", clientidd);
                    params.put("doc_type",myList);
                    params.put("taxpreparerid", taxpreid);

                    System.out.println("my lIst"+myList);
                    System.out.println(params);

                    return null;
                }
```

1) getParams() method only accept String hashmap . as you can see

> `Map<String, String> getParams()`

you are passing  `Map<String, Object>`

2) If you are setting your hashmap . you have to return it too :D

> return params ;

You are passing `return null`

3) You can't send List object directly like that . If you want to pass List like that . you need to convert it to String (I wouldn't recommend that way).

> params.put("doc_type",myList);

This is wrong . I hope you get my points

Comment: I changes i done.

Comment: Which Method do you recomended for me ,please share any link you have?

Comment: I am using this to convert Arraylist to String:  myList= new ArrayList<String>();
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        final String newData=gson.toJson(myList);

Comment: I solved it ,Thanks Sir

Comment: @RAHUL *For Your question:*  if you want to send json data to server , you're gonna have to send JsonObjectRequest . 
 and I'm glad now you solved it